# I have some troubles with a post request

Tags: python, post, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** a website but i get a 500 response.
It's a relocation website and i'm trying to get prices for different input parameters (volume, destination, departureCity ...).

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.demenagerfacile.com/devis/create"

payload = "volume_set_with_vcalc=false&id_vc_quote=&mode=MOVE_CLASSIC&fromCity=150+Rue+Saint-Maur%2C+Paris%2C+France&locationDeparture=%7B%22lat%22%3A%2248.8690238%22%2C%22lng%22%3A%222.3745715999999675%22%7D&placeIdDeparture=%22ChIJOTRebuRt5kcRoklIrmMZx6Y%22&countryDep=FR&toCity=Rue+de+Marseille%2C+Lyon%2C+France&locationDestination=%7B%22lat%22%3A%2245.7509119%22%2C%22lng%22%3A%224.83963289999997%22%7D&placeIdDestination=%22Eh5SdWUgZGUgTWFyc2VpbGxlLCBMeW9uLCBGcmFuY2UiLiosChQKEgm7NI_oRer0RxEcVzzVtXmrQxIUChIJl4foalHq9EcR8CG75CqrCAQ%22&countryDest=FR&fixedDate=on&date=2019-07-18&volume=30"
headers = {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "cookie": "PHPSESSID=k3f99mg9urimu9dpc1ot7vudf5; __stripe_mid=e5c971f7-5e78-4e61-92db-a62dda48fd2c; _ga=GA1.2.110393239.1561101566; _gid=GA1.2.1597485519.1561101566; previousServerId=0; _fbp=fb.1.1561101566214.588023040; _hjIncludedInSample=1; hubspotutk=e7e9f524c880e1091d415cfc5cbd4903; __hssrc=1; apzContact=%5B%7B%22buttonIdKey%22%3A%229deacb07173c79d76baf4f58c56037ad%22%2C%22apizeeSessionId%22%3A%22334d6232-930f-41ec-aab9-0753c7b3036a%22%2C%22apiconfSession%22%3A%229deacb07173c79d76baf4f58c56037ad%22%2C%22apiconfOfflineMessageState%22%3Anull%7D%5D; cookiebanner-accepted=1; __stripe_sid=5e2fb6df-ea5c-470a-98f3-44e172955633; __hstc=78993675.e7e9f524c880e1091d415cfc5cbd4903.1561101566944.1561101566944.1561106755827.2; _gat_UA-65262710-1=1; __hssc=78993675.3.1561106755827; apiCCId=334d6232-930f-41ec-aab9-0753c7b3036a-0000; apiKey=d7897a4712a9413c3a363e737954d853; sessionId=230a5a70-9401-11e9-935a-19ca5a0a60c1",
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload)

print(response)
```

Comment: error 500 is a server-side error. Maybe the url requires certain cookies to work. Try adding the cookies from your browser onto the header and see if it still happens.

Comment: thnks ! i've already tried adding cookies from my browser to the headers but still doesn't work

Comment: just add all your browser headers and see if it works then, add the user agent too! If it still doesn't work then it's probably the server at fault. Also i suggest you remove the cookie from your post. It's not safe to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests’ simple API means that all forms of HTTP request are as obvious. For example, this is how you make an HTTP [POST request](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

**Replace your code**

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload)
```

**TO**

```
response = requests.post(url,headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @mhabak1 I just checked and it seems to be working,
Please add headers while posting the request like below,

```
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Thanks